# How to properly and simply setup Gitlab-CI/CD for a Java spring project

Tags: java, spring, maven, configuration, gitlab-ci

I'am trying to use Gitlab-ci as my CI/CD pipeline for a maven java spring multi-module project. How to setup / fix my configuration?

---

> **Solved**:
>   Finally, i found that i had to use jUNITRunner + specifying my .sql scripts into my test classes, instead of thinking that gitlab could do it (I think it's possible, but i failed i implementing it).
>   i added this to my test classes:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/com/dummy/myerp/testbusiness/business/bootstrapContext.xml"})
@Sql(scripts = { "classpath:/com/dummy/myerp/technical/01_create_schema.sql",
        "classpath:/com/dummy/myerp/technical/02_create_tables.sql",
        "classpath:/com/dummy/myerp/technical/21_insert_data_demo.sql" })
public class TestIntComptabiliteManagerImpl extends BusinessTestCase{
```

> Aso fixed my .sql script adding DROP SCHEMA:

```
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS MYERP cascade;
CREATE SCHEMA MYERP;
```

---

> 13/05/19 error:
>   I have tested many options, some of them worked, other not. Currently, i am getting a "**failed connection**" or "**connection refused**" when gitlab attempt to run my **test-business** profile.
>   16/05/19 error: I tried to modify the url into the `datasource.properties` file like that: `url=jdbc:postgresql://runner@postgres:5432/db_myerp` instead of localhost:9032 (i used this url for my local integration-tests) but now i got an error:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
    at com.dummy.myerp.testbusiness.business.TestIntComptabiliteManagerImpl.insertEcritureComptable(TestIntComptabiliteManagerImpl.java:127)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
    at com.dummy.myerp.testbusiness.business.TestIntComptabiliteManagerImpl.insertEcritureComptable(TestIntComptabiliteManagerImpl.java:127)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: runner@postgres
    at com.dummy.myerp.testbusiness.business.TestIntComptabiliteManagerImpl.insertEcritureComptable(TestIntComptabiliteManagerImpl.java:127)
```

I tried to setup a `bootstrapContext.xml` file to load other contexts.
I also tried to add a `datasource.properties` file.
I used to modify many times my `.gitlab-ci.yml` configuration file.

I have junit tests that i run locally and integration tests ("test-business" profile) that i want to run on gitlab-ci.com using their online CI/CD solution.

## My setup:

Here is my file tree in intelliJ:
[File Tree in IntelliJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEuTM.png)
[File Tree 2nd part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFiGF.png)

### gitlab-ci.yml:

```
---
before_script:

image: "maven:latest"
services:
  - "postgres:latest"
stages:
  - test
test:
  script:
    - "echo \" TEST INTEGRATION - BUSINESS\""
    - "mvn clean install -f src/pom.xml -P test-business"
  stage: test
variables:
  DATABASE_URL: "postgres://runner@postgres:5432/db_myerp
  POSTGRES_DB: db_myerp
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: myerp
  POSTGRES_SCRIPT_CREATION_SCHEMA: 01_create_schema.sql
  POSTGRES_SCRIPT_CREATION_TABLES: 02_create_tables.sql
  POSTGRES_SCRIPT_INSERT_DATA: 21_insert_data_demo.sql
  POSTGRES_USER: usr_myerp
```

*(Note: the `-f src/pom.xml` is to precise where is my pom.xml file for gitlab, because he isn't into the root of gitlab.)*

### datasource.properties (into myerp-business ... resources)

```
driver=org.postgresql.Driver
url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db_myerp
dbuser=usr_myerp
dbpassword=myerp
```

*Note: About the url, iam not sure, i tried to change it different times for testing purpose. Locally on my computer, i use a docker on localhost:9032, but on gitlab-ci, i should use the docker service, right?*

#### BootstrapContext.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:ctx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>datasource.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="false"/>
        <property name="fileEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </bean>
   <!-- <bean id = "dataSourceMYERP"
          class = "org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name = "driverClassName" value = "org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name = "url" value = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:9032/db_myerp"/>
        <property name = "username" value = "usr_myerp"/>
        <property name = "password" value = "myerp"/>
    </bean>-->
    <import resource="classpath:com/dummy/myerp/business/applicationContext.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath:com/dummy/myerp/business/transactionContext.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath:com/dummy/myerp/consumer/sqlContext.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath:com/dummy/myerp/consumer/applicationContext.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath:com/dummy/myerp/technical/applicationContext.xml"/>
</beans>
```

#### Parent pom.xml :

[Link to parent pom.xml](https://pastebin.com/Mg8JicK0)

#### In summary:

I have a multi-module project that use unit test and integration tests. 
Locally, i use a docker who run my local postgreSQL. For now tests are working.
I would like to properly use the Gitlab-ci/cd online solution, but iam a bit stuck understanding how everything is working, and how i should configure it in the most simplest way possible.